# How to set RelativeLayout parent right side

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am very new for android and here I have created two `RelativeLayout` on `LinearLayout`

My requirement is I want to set second Relative Layout at parent right side

According to my code screen seems to be like my below image

So how can I set second `RelativeLayout` at parent right side

### code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ItemCode"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="GG00929-023"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Price"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="176000"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="On Hand"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="372.89"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Reserve"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="0.68"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Cut Qty"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="0.00"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Balance"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="372.89"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Add android:layout_alignParentRight="true" attribute for second relative layout

Comment: then try android:layout_gravity=right

Comment: set parent linear layout `orientation='horizontal'` .............

Comment: yes i set but still no use

Comment: what do u mean i already set that

Comment: @Krish Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try this `Layout`. I have applied some changes to your Layout. I have remove child `Linear Layout` because it is useless or `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` will not get affected. Also added `Relative Layout as your Root Layout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RL1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ItemCode"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="GG00929-023"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="176000"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="On Hand"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="372.89"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Reserve"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="0.68"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Cut Qty"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="0.00"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Balance"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="372.89"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Krish Cheers!! Glad to help you. :).

Comment: @Krish You should accept my answer as i have given first in queue thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

Linear Layout has no such attribute to set Right:
So you have to add the view with weight which will coverup the middle blank space.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ItemCode"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="GG00929-023"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="176000"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="On Hand"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="372.89"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Reserve"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="0.68"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Cut Qty"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="0.00"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Balance"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=":"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="372.89"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: @Krish Applying by view is a bad habit to design your layout. it will not stable if you want to add some more widgets to your layout after words.

Answer (score 0):

Between the two `RelativeLayout`, insert a third `View`:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Because of it's layout weight, this will "push" your second `RelativeLayout` to the right side.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use android:layout_alignParentRight="true", the parent should be RelativeLayout. The parent of your RelativeLayout is LinearLayout and if I'm not mistaken, you want that RelativeLayout to be at the right of parent. Either make the parent RelativeLayout, or give weight_sum to LinearLayout and weight to the children.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in second `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">
```

`android:layout_alignParentRight` attribute only work in children of `RelativeLayout`. Now, you are using it in a child of a `LinearLayout` so it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have few ways to do what you require. Ill give you 2.

- First you can change the "Parent Layout" to Relative and add         alignParentRight="true" and alignParentLeft="true" for the two LinearLayout.
- Second, with the way you did it, you can change to width of the two LinearLayout to 0dp and then, add them layout_weight="1".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ItemCode"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="GG00929-023"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Price"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="176000"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="On Hand"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="372.89"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Reserve"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="0.68"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Cut Qty"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="0.00"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Balance"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="372.89"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]